# How to use regular expressions to get the string " css " from the line written below?

Tags: css, regex

How to use regular expressions to get the string **'css'** from the line written below?

```
<link href="http://b2b.ap/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Do you need to use regular expressions? You cannot use javascript to get DOM node and proper attribute and do some strings manipulations?

Comment: Yes use Javascript here !

Comment: The string "css" is in two places in that string. Which one do you want? Are you trying to find "the first directory after the domain in a URL"? Or are you trying to get "the file extension of the file called by the URL"?

Or do you just literally want to find the string "css" (and count it or replace it or something)?

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you're expecting, the following regex will check if the file extension is css or not.

```js
var regex = /.\.css$/;
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0];
console.log(x);
console.log(regex.test(x.href));
```

```html
<link href="http://b2b.ap/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you manipulate the string, try this:

```js
var str = `
<link href="http://b2b.ap/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
`;

var pattern = /<link.+?href=\"(.+\.css)\".*?>/;

var match = str.match(pattern);

console.log(match[1]);
```